# EF Core 2.1 Select fields for one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a class that owns a list of entities:

```
public class Dad
{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public string SecretName{get;set;}

    public List<Kid> Kids{get;set;}
}

public class Kid
{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string SecretName{get;set;}
    public Dad Dad {get;set;
}
```

I am trying to specify what columns to select in the Kids that are owned by Dad:

```
var DadAPIResponse = _context.Dads
            .Where(o.Id == Id)
            .Select(x => new {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name
                // Here, I need something like
                // Kids = {Id, Name}
            }).AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

My intention is to return a list of Dads but only show their Id, Name and only show the Id and Name of each of the Kids owned by that Dad.

I am using EF Core 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate your entity model from the model you are returning and only include the needed properties of each type as:

```
public class DadModel
{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<Kid> Kids{get;set;}
}
```

...and:

```
public class KidModel
{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Since this new Kid-model does not have a reference to its Dad, you also avoid any kind of circular reference issue.
You may then select the kids of each dad by:

```
var response = _context.Dads
            .Where(d.Id == Id)
            .Select(d => new DadModel{
                Id = d.Id,
                Name = d.Name
                Kids = d.Kids.Select(k => new KidsModel
                {
                    Id = k.Id,
                    Name = k.Name
                }).ToList()
            }).AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the "d.Kids.Select" part.